# How to decode a word and return the decoded result in php using explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I want to decode a word and return the decoded result. My coded word is "dtgcm" and I need to find the location of each letter in the alphabet. I exploded the alphabet into an array.

```
<?php    
$alphabet = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z';    
$alphaex = explode(' ',$alphabet);    
print_r($alphaex);    
?>
```

But when I find the letter, I need to back it up by 2 and retrieve that letter to decipher the code. So the decoded word would be "break". But I also need to make that if the word starts with "a" it would back up 2 and get "y" and when starts with "b", backing up 2 will get "z".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ord` to get the ASCII value of each character and `chr` to convert it back.

```
$new = '';
foreach (str_split("dtgcm") as $char) {
    $decode = ord($char);
    if ($decode <= 98) {
        $decode += 24;
    }
    else {
        $decode -= 2;
    }
    $new .= chr($decode);
}
echo $new;
```